# pyserial doesn't work once terminaite with "ctrl+c", only recover until reboot?

Tags: python, ubuntu, serial-port

Move my program from winxp to ubuntu, meet a strange problem.

I test it like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import time
from platform import system
import serial
if system()=="Windows":
    serId =2
else:
    serId = '/dev/ttyUSB0'


ser= serial.Serial(serId, 115200, timeout=1)

while True:
    start=time.time()
    ser.write('1')
    t=ser.read(128)
    print time.time()-start
    print len([i for i in t if i != '']), t
```

on win, it's ok.
output:

```
0.9

128 ************************************************
```

on Ubuntu, 
at first, seems same as win.
but,when I terminate with Ctrl+C, and reStart it.

```
time will be 3s and even more
can receive all the 128B content I send.
```

I add `ser.flush()` before `write` and `read`. Nothing change.

What wrong in it? Is there something special cause the difference between ubuntu and xp?